# How to change form action dynamically with Laravel + VueJS

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have a route setup like this:

```
Route::post('subjects/{subject}/{tag}', 'TagController@show');
```

And I have the following form structure, where I am populating the `options` of a `select` element by looping through a `$tags` array:

```
<form id="tagForm" method="POST"
action="/subjects/{{ $lesson->subject->slug }}/{{ 'selected option will go here' }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
   <div class="select">
      <select @change="onTagSelected">
        <option>Tags</option>
        @foreach ($tags as $tag)
                <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->title }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I change the form action according to the currently selected tag from the option?

I am using Vue.js as js framework and I am listening for `onchange` event:

```
onTagSelected: function(event) {
        var tagForm = document.getElementById('tagForm');
// what should I do here to change the action?
        tagForm.submit();
}
```

Comment: You need JavaScript for that if I understand you correctly

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that I am using vuejs as js framework. And if you look at the select tag, you will see that I have already attached an event listener. I just don't know what to do in there in order to change the action and then submit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you've solved it, you're not really using VueJS, and flat javascript would make more sense. A more VueJS approach would be something like this: (presuming you're writing in a Blade View, this would need to be in a )

```
new Vue({
   data: function() {
      return {
         form: {
             baseAction: "/subjects/{{ $lesson->subject->slug }}/",
             chosenAction: '',
         }
      }
   },
   computed: {
       computedAction: function() {
           return this.form.baseAction + this.form.chosenAction;
       }
   }
});
```

Now for your form:

```
<form action="computedAction">
```

And for your select:

```
<select v-model="form.chosenAction">
```

The onchange isn't necessary here as we're binding the value of the selected  to the `chosenAction` property of the `form object`. We then use the `computedAction` property (which is a computed value, of course) to dictate the action of our form.

**EDIT** - When using a transpiled vuejs approach with single file components:

If you want vuejs to be responsible for the life-cycle of the form, then you can use a single file component:

```
<template>
    <form id="tagForm" method="POST" action="computedAction">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="token"/>
        <div class="select">
            <select v-model="form.chosenAction">
                <option value="">Tags</option>
                <option v-for="tag in tags" value="tag.id"> {{tag.title}} </option>
            </select>
        </div>
     </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['tags', 'slug', 'token']
        data: function() {
            return {
               form: {
                   chosenAction: ''
               }
            }
       },

       computed: {
           computedAction: function() {
               return `/subjects/${slug}/${this.form.chosenAction}`
           }
       }
    }
</script>
```

Now in your app.js file you need to tell Vue about this new component so you can use it in your blade template. This needs to come after you use `import Vue from 'vue'` in your `app.js` file.

```
import MyCoolForm from './path/to/my/cool/form.js';

Vue.component('v-mycoolform', MyCoolForm);
```

Now in your blade template, you can pass properties to this component:

```
<v-mycoolform :slug="{{$lesson->subject->slug}}" :token="{{csrf_token()}}" :tags="{{json_encode($tags)}}"/>
```

Comment: How can I attach `{{ $lesson->subject->slug }}`  to the `baseAction` property? You are directly referring the blade syntax in vue, I have to send the value of it from blade to vue. How can I do that?

Comment: @Eisenheim Is your `Vue` in a separate file, not inside of a <script> block in a blade template?

Comment: Yes, separated. in app.js file. I am thinking of something like this: `<select @change="onTagSelected({{ $lesson->subject->slug }})" v-model="form.chosenAction">` And then maybe I can append the value to baseAction?

Comment: @Eisenheim K, sec

Comment: @Eisenheim Added the single file approach

Comment: I need to keep the form in `.blade.php` file, what you are suggesting is to move the entire form to a dedicated `.vue` file which requires additional setup (import+component registration). Is there a way to send a variable from blade to vue? I tried this: `onTagSelected($event, {{ $lesson->subject->slug }})` but vue is receiving `NaN` from second argument.

Comment: Well, the idea is to let Vue be responsible for the entire layer. Display, Functionality, Interaction. If you don't want to use the approaches I've outlined above, just use plaint javascript, you're not really taking advantage of Vue at that point.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort and understand your point. But the thing is, I am not going to reuse this form. I have to go through all the steps you've mentioned above only to use the `<v-mycoolform>` component once.

Comment: @Eisenheim I definitely get that, it's not always for everyone. If you're just using it once, just stick the vue code in the <script> tag in the blade view. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to bind the `select` tag to a [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage) property:

```
<form id="tagForm" method="POST" action="/subjects/{{ $lesson->subject->slug }}/">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
   <div class="select">
      <select @change="onTagSelected" v-model="selectedTag">
        <option>Tags</option>
        @foreach ($tags as $tag)
            <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->title }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

And in my event listener, I am appending the property to the action and then submitting it:

```
onTagSelected: function(event) {
        var tagForm = document.getElementById('tagForm');
        tagForm.action += this.selectedTag;
        // console.log(tagForm.action);
        tagForm.submit();
}
```

Although this solves my problem, but I am not happy with it. I think there is better way to do this. Please feel free to share the best solution for circumstances like this.